# How can retrieve only name on contact in android

Tags: android, telephony

I use a below code, but I need only contact name and this code retrieve all data from contact, Facebook ,Nimbuzz and ....
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(

```
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        //numberPhone = 0;
        contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));



        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                Long.parseLong(contactId));
        Uri dataUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri,
                Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);

        try {
            Cursor nameCursor = getContentResolver()
                    .query(dataUri,null,Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",new String[] { StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE }, null);
            int indexDisplayName = nameCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME);
            nameCursor.moveToFirst();
            do {

                String firstName = nameCursor.getString(nameCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(Data.DATA2));
                String lastName = nameCursor.getString(nameCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(Data.DATA3));
                Arrayename.add(firstName+" "+lastName);
                //String display = nameCursor.getString(indexDisplayName);





                //Log.d("display name", "display name is: " + display);

            } while (nameCursor.moveToNext());
            nameCursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Happend While Reading Names",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

how can fetch only contact data?

Answer (score 0):

If i'm getting you correctly below is what you need:

create a xml file for displaying results which will get:

1. create a button will will fire up the intent:
2. create a textview or edittext(i have used edit text)

Start an intent like this calling startActivityforresult(its args....) on button click:

```
 final static int CONTACTS_RESULT = 3;

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACTS_RESULT);
```

Then handle the result on callback:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {

    case CONTACTS_RESULT:

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri returnedData = data.getData();
            id = returnedData.getLastPathSegment();

            name = retriveName(data);
            etName.setText(name);
          }

         break;
              }

       }
```

// This method is for getting the Name of the contact and setting its value to the returned value by calling setText() on the

```
private String retriveName(Intent data) 
           {
    String name = null;
    Uri returnedData = data.getData();
    String id = returnedData.getLastPathSegment();

    // Cursor for name

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(returnedData, null, null,
            null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
                               {

        name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


    }
    return name;

}
```

See if this works for you....

EDIT: Have you tried replacing Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME with these two:

1. Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
2. Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_SOURCE

Comment: i know this, but with this i get all contact information such facebook app or any app that interact with contact, but i want only show contact info that user added into contact

Comment: i can catch name,but i have a lot of name that dosent in the my contact, i think facebook contact and other contact sync with my phone contact that i dont need in my programm